# How many pairs are in $(B,C) \in P(A) \times P(A)$ such that $B \subseteq C$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I'm trying to solve this problem:
Let $A = \{1,2,3,\ldots,n \}$

How many pairs are in $(B,C) \in P(A) \times P(A)$ such that $B \subseteq C$

I want to solve this using combinatorics,

Basically what I know is that for every $x \in A$ we have the possibilities:

1) $x \in B$

2) $x \in C \setminus B$

3) $x \notin B$ and $x \notin C$

And I know that for every $C$ I take, there could be $2^k$ possibilities for $B$ since $B$ is a subset of $C$, but I'm having trouble counting the possibilities for $C$.

Some help?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $\#$ denote the number of elements. $\#(C)=k\implies B$ has $2^k$ choices. As $C\subseteq A$, $k$ can vary from $0$ to $n$. As $\#(C)=k$ gives us $\binom{n}{k}$ choices for $C$, total number of choices 
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}2^k=(1+2)^n=3^n
$$

Comment: Can you please explain why you queried the number of sizes $C$ can hold? Because this is an excellent way of proving it but I still have some trouble understanding why you chose to first calculate the possibilities for the sizes of C and not it's elements

Answer (score 5):

As you said, for each element $i = 1,2,\dots,n$, you must decide whether: (1) $i$ will belong to both $B$ and $C$; (2) $i$ will belong to $C$, but not to $B$; or (3) $i$ will belong to neither $B$ nor $C$.

For every $i = 1, 2, \dots, n$, there are three possible choices. Therefore the number of possible choices for $B$ and $C$ is $3^n$.

Comment: But I pick elements from $P(A)$, doesn't that say that I need to pick from $2^n$ elements?

Comment: Choosing $B$ and $C$ amounts to the same thing as deciding for each element $i$ of $A$ which sets, of $B$ and $C$, element $i$ will belong to.